# AngularJS directive wait for promise in prelink

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I want so create a plugin system within my app.
In my first version there should be a plugin-folder where I put my plugins in their own folder.

Every plugin has its own directive wich should be loaded at runtime.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
-plugins
--plugin1
---directive_plugin1.js
---plugin1.html
--plugin2
---directive_plugin2.js
---plugin2.html
```

In my app there are some registered plugins that looks like this:

```
$rootScope.registered_plugins = ['plugin1', 'plugin2'];
```

So I setup an plugin directive which looks like this:

```
module.directive('plugin', ['$compile', 'angularLoad', function($compile, angularLoad) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { 'plugin': '@' },
            compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                        console.log('PRE!');

                        var load_script = function() {
                            var url = '/js/plugins/' + scope.plugin + '/directive_' + scope.plugin + '.js';
                            var load = angularLoad.loadScript(url);

                            load.then(function () {
                                console.log('LOADED!');
                            });

                            load.catch(function () {
                                console.log('NOT LOADED!');
                            });
                        };

                        load_script();

                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
                        console.log('POST!');
                        var template = '<' + scope.plugin + ' />';
                        var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
                        element.append(compiled);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }]);
```

My plugin factory looks like this:

```
module.factory('pluginfactory', function ($q, $timeout) {
    return function(key) {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
            d.resolve(key);
        }, 1);

        return d.promise;
    };
});
```

My plugin1 directive looks like this:

```
module.directive('plugin1', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: '/js/plugins/plugin1/plugin1.html'
   };
});
```

My plugin1 html looks like this:

```
<p>Hello, I am plugin1</p>
```

My plugin2 directive looks like this:

```
module.directive('plugin2', function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: '/js/plugins/plugin2/plugin2.html'
   };
});
```

My plugin2 html looks like this:

```
<p>Hello, I am plugin2</p>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
module.controller('PluginController', function($scope, pluginfactory){
        $scope.reset_loading();

        $scope.templates = [
            {template: {url: $scope.folder_plugin + '/plugin_content.html'}}
        ];

        $scope.template_plugin_content = $scope.templates[0].template;
        $scope.validated_plugins = [];

        $scope.validate_plugins = function() {
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.registered_plugins.length; i++) {
                var key = $scope.registered_plugins[i];
                pluginfactory(key).then(function (plugin) {
                    $scope.validated_plugins.push(plugin);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

My plugin html looks like this (It's using the PluginController):

```
<div class="col2">
    <div class="container-inner"
         ng-init="validate_plugins()">
        <h1>{{ 'PLUGIN_CONTENT' | translate }}</h1>

        <div ng-repeat="p in validated_plugins">
            <plugin plugin='{{ p }}'></plugin>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the main problem is, that I want to preload the plugin1 and plugin2 directives in the prelink process of the plugin directive. I read that angular-load should do that for me.

When I execute the code the content of the plugins look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="p in validated_plugins" class="ng-scope">
            <plugin plugin="plugin1" class="ng-isolate-scope"><plugin1 class="ng-scope"></plugin1></plugin>
        </div>

<div ng-repeat="p in validated_plugins" class="ng-scope">
            <plugin plugin="plugin2" class="ng-isolate-scope"><plugin2 class="ng-scope"></plugin2></plugin>
        </div>
```

So, basically the p elements are not set.

The code that angular-load produces at runtime looks like this:

```
<script src="/js/plugins/plugin1/directive_plugin1.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/plugin2/directive_plugin2.js"></script>
```

When I copy and paste both of the lines in my code and load the app it works as it should. Both p elements are shown correctly.

The console log shows me this:

```
directive_plugin.js:8 PRE!
directive_plugin.js:27 POST!
directive_plugin.js:8 PRE!
directive_plugin.js:27 POST!
2directive_plugin.js:15 LOADED!
```

So I see, that the problem is the asynchronous function of angular-load.

Is there a way to wait for the loadScript-method in the preLink-function of the plugin directive before the postLink-function is executed?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this kind of hack.

Since the scope is shared between the two function (pre and post) why not place the load promise in it and wait for it to resolve :

```js
    compile: function(element, attrs, transclude) {
      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          console.log('PRE!');

          var load_script = function() {
            var url = '/js/plugins/' + scope.plugin + '/directive_' + scope.plugin + '.js';

            // storing the promise in the scope
            scope.isLoadedPromise = angularLoad.loadScript(url);

            scope.isLoadedPromise.then(function() {
              console.log('LOADED!');
            }).catch(function() {
              console.log('NOT LOADED!');
            });
          };

          load_script();

        },
        post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          console.log('POST!');

          // waiting for the loading to finish
          scope.isLoadedPromise.then(function() {
            console.log('YES IT IS LOADED!');
            var template = '<' + scope.plugin + ' />';
            var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
            element.append(compiled);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```